# Importance of UX in B2C Vs B2B

Tags: ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

I'm currently analyzing the impact of UX in B2B and B2C sites. I have identified the focal points of UX in B2C sites whereas I'm not so certain whether those same concepts are directly applicable for B2B sites as well. Is there a difference ? Can someone suggest good reference material for me to go through?

Answer (score 2):

You tried Googling 'ux differences b2b b2c', right?

These are listed in order of quality.

If by "reference material" you mean published studies or scholarly articles, I think you're probably going to be disappointed on that front.

---

**B2B vs. B2C Websites: Key UX Differences**

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/b2b-vs-b2c/

**6 Differences Between B2B and B2C Usability**

https://measuringu.com/b2b-usability/

**User Experience: Designing Your Website for B2B vs. B2C**

https://www.semrush.com/blog/user-experience-designing-your-website-for-b2b-vs-b2c/

**B2B vs B2C UX...what are the key differences?**

https://www.reddit.com/r/userexperience/comments/5454s0/b2b_vs_b2c_uxwhat_are_the_key_differences/